# Extending Django's User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration

I have been dealing for a while with Django's authentication system and I just cannot understand why I have to go through this process [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)! :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

... rather than simply extending the "User" class like this:

```
class Employee(User):
     ....
```

... and re-using all the code contained within. I have taken a look at articles like: [b-list.org](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/)! , and I understand that the problem may be related with the automatic Django database management.

Is there a way in which I can automatically extend the User model without having to create an additional table in the database, so that Django modifies the current database table for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to obey the fellas of the django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Because only abstract models don't create tables in django and built-in user model is not

Comment: The question is precisely based on that example. The thing is that I would like to know the actual reason why this problem is handled this way.

Comment: the reason is that built-in user class is not an abstract model. Abstract models should explicitly declare that in their meta class